# Not able to remove all fields with a prefix in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have following fields after I have parsed my JSON in Logstash.

```
parsedcontent.userinfo.appId
parsedcontent.userinfo.deviceId
parsedcontent.userinfo.id
parsedcontent.userinfo.token
parsedcontent.userinfo.type.
```

I want to remove all these fields using a filter. I can do it with :

```
filter{
  mutate{
     remove_field => "[parsedcontent][userinfo][appId]"
  }
}
```

But I have to write field names with same prefix many times and I have many such kind of fields. Is there any filter to remove fields with a prefix easily? Please guide.

Answer (score -1):

You can use wildcards or regex.

```
filter {
    mutate {
        remove_field => "[parsedcontent*]"
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't find documentation that this works. Source?

Comment: This is not true